# Defining closures in a loop - how to prevent a variable mutating

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I have the following workflow code:

```
stage "Deploy to Prod Sites"
def branches = [:]
for (i=0; i< sites.size(); i++) {
  site=sites[i]
  echo "site = $site"
  branches[site] = {  
    buildJob (app, site, revision)
  }
}

parallel branches
```

When I run this, each branch has the same value for `site`.

How do I ensure that the value of `site` contains the value from when the closure was defined rather than run?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is `def site`

so

```
stage "Deploy to Prod Sites"
def branches = [:]
for (i=0; i< sites.size(); i++) {
  def site=sites[i]
  echo "site = $site"
  branches[site] = {  
    buildJob (app, site, revision)
  }
}

parallel branches
```

This now works as expected.